# Is there a view to list down the users of Security Group

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am using Windows XP joined to a domain.

I have a security group for which I am the owner.

How can I view the members of the security group from a client computer such as Windows XP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to list (and optionally add or remove) members of a domain group, the simplest way to do so with the out of box tools is with `net.exe`:

list:

```
NET GROUP groupname /DOMAIN
```

add:

```
NET GROUP groupname username /ADD /DOMAIN
```

remove:

```
NET GROUP groupname username /DELETE /DOMAIN
```

Be sure to add double-quotes around the group- or usernames if they include spaces or other special characters. Also be aware that using this method you can only target the groups of the domain to which the local machine is joined.

Comment: This answer shows users but will not show any embedded groups.  To see those, can try this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/801223/261679) (Windows 8).

Comment: NET GROUP didn't return anything for me. I used NET LOCALGROUP groupname /DOMAIN

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the "Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack"

> The Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack (adminpak.msi) provides server management tools that allow administrators to remotely manage Windows 2000 Servers & Windows Server 2003 family servers. This is the final version (build 3790) of the adminpak.msi file.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16770

But if you just want to view the members you can use try dsget. I'm not sure but I think it's avaliable on Windows XP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731202(v=ws.10).aspx

You can also try a LDAP browser. There's one free here: http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm

But the easiest way it still is the Admin Pack. It allows you to control the members.
If you want just some method to save the members to a file, working with dsget is the best option.