# How to list the users and groups of an AD Security Group when not a domain admin

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-groups

I am on Windows 8 connected to domain.

I wish to view the users and groups of an AD Security group.  I am not the owner of the group.  The command:

```
net group /domain TheGroupName
```

shows the direct users of that group ***but does not show the groups*** within the group.

As an alternative to the Windows 8, I also have remote access to a Windows Server 2008 R2 and am an admin for that machine but not an admin for the domain.  The program "dsget" does not appear to be installed.

This question is expanding on [this one (511715)](https://superuser.com/questions/511715/is-there-a-view-to-list-down-the-users-of-security-group/517134#517134)

Comment: If you want a better answer to an already existing question.  The proper procedure is to offer a bounty to that existing question.

Comment: That question has been answered as it was phased. This is a new but very related question.

Comment: What makes you think you should have access to obtain the lists of users and groups if you aren't a domain administrator (or have the appropriate specific permission, whatever that might be, on your domain account)? To me the opposite would seem intuitive.

Comment: That command works for me now, and as far as I know I am not a Domain Admin.  Are you saying I must be?  I don't think I am the owner of the group either.

Comment: The 'Search Active Directory' function from My Computer->Network will grant you the access to view groups and basic user information without special permissions.

Comment: You might also be able to query AD using LDAP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224465/querying-windows-active-directory-server-using-ldapsearch-from-command-line

Comment: You might not have the appropriate access in Active Directory to query groups. Local permissions != domain permissions

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If you're a local admin setting up a share on a local computer's drive and adding an active directory usergroup, you'd better be able to look up who exactly you are granting access to (at least at present...obviously, a domain admin can add and delete users to a usergroup after you check)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Go to 'Computer', click on 'Network' from the left menu, in the top bar select 'Search Active Directory'

You should be able to search for groups and view membership here, even if not an admin.

[image: Access 'Search Active Directory']

Comment: "So easy a non-domain admin can do it."  I didn't realize 'Computer' meant within explorer or Alt-Q 'Network'. Can even double click to drill down.  Thanks.  Don't know why this was not an answer to the linked question, because its only for Windows 8?

Comment: I hadn't seen the other question but no, this works on Win7 and, I think, Vista even. :) 

I recently found it like a month ago and have been telling everyone I know since lol

Comment: This dialog has been around forever. IIRC Windows 2000 contains it, too.

Comment: Command line (or Run) equivalent: `"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" dsquery.dll,OpenQueryWindow`

Comment: Where is the equivalent in Windows 10?

Comment: @flickerfly in W10, just click on the top of the window on Network (File Network View) and you'll see the "Search Active Directory" thing. seems that "ribbon" (is that what it's called ?) is hidden by default. I've added another answer with a more straightforward way to call this program, and I have a handy shortcut to that command now.

Comment: I don't see how you go from this to finding the members in the group once you search and locate the group.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @StatsStudent - double click on any found groups and you will see the subgroups/users within.

Answer (score 44):

Run this from a command prompt to get the complete membership of an AD group (users AND groups). Tested on Windows 10.

```
Rundll32 dsquery.dll OpenQueryWindow
```

There's a handy Advanced Tab in there that supports partial string searches (starting with, ending with).

Comment: Works on Windows 7 as well. Cheers.

Comment: Less clicking, same results +1

Comment: To make this more accessible: Add a "start" infront, put this in `userq.bat` in `system32`. Then open the dialog via the `Run`-dialog (WINDOWS + R) and `userq`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to list the members of a group.  It only lists the groups.

Comment: How can I query other domain objects. With this command I can query only object of the domain to which my laptop is connected.

Answer (score 13):

Sysinternals offers [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907), a utility for listing the complete LDAP structure of an AD forest. It’s slighty overkill for your intended use, though.

I don’t know which permissions exactly are necessary for querying this data, but I guess any logged-in user can do it. I never had any problems querying just about everything, but maybe the domain at work isn’t secured properly.

Usability note: You need not enter your credentials if you’re logged on as a domain user.

You do, however, need the IP address or host name of a Domain Controller. It’s likely this is the same as your DNS server, so just fire up `nslookup` and try the address displayed there.

Comment: You can open up a command prompt and do "echo %LOGONSERVER%" to see the AD server the computer used for authentication. In addition, you should be able to do "nslookup my.domain.name" to list all the AD servers. So if you login using "mydomain\myuser" try "nslookup mydomain"

Comment: leaving all fields (IP, User, Pw) blank worked for me